# Regex to add option for OR operation

Tags: php, regex

Here is my  regex to scrap image from page.

```
preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches
```

But it fails when image url is like this:

```
src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Adolescent_girl_sad_0001.jpg/200px-Adolescent_girl_sad_0001.jpg"
```

I think it need to add `OR` operation in above regex to allove image starting with `//`.

documentation says `|` pipe will do or operation. But how to add it in above regex?

Comment: You already have used it successfully in the `(?:png|jpg)` part, so why not do it again?

Comment: BTW, it would be easier to make `https?` [as a whole](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) than to use some [alternatives (pipe)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

Comment: Are you looking for image links in Wikipedia pages? For those, there even is a special API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#images_.2F_im

Comment: @Bergi: i already tried this: `if(preg_match_all('/\bhttps?:|//\/\/\S+(?:png|jpg)\b/', $html, $matches))` which give error `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '/' in F:\wamp\www\img.php on line 10`

Comment: Is it ok to just parse out the "src" value, using '/src=([\'|"])(.+?)\1/'

Comment: @Andrew: it is cool but I only want to parse src for image

Comment: If you only want png|jpg, then '/<img[^>]+src=([\'"])([^>\'"]+?\.(?:png|jpg))\1/i'

Comment: @Programming_crazy: What you were looking for is `'/\b(https?\/\/:|\/\/)\S+…`

Comment: @Andrew: to get the result `$matches[0][0];` is ok? it give nothing

Comment: @Andrew [THE PONY HE COMES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Empty? See this: http://ideone.com/sHnRWx. -> string(6) "xx.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

You could just avoid the wrath of the pony instead...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$sources = array();
foreach($image as $img) $sources[] = $img->getAttribute("src");
```

Done!

Comment: But that might match non-png/jpg images as well…

Comment: @Niet: What if I want to get only one image?

Comment: @Bergi It is trivial to add a simple "if" to check the extension. A more valid comment would have been that I put `href` instead of `src`.

Comment: @Programming_crazy Depends which image you want. If it's the first, `$images->item(0)` is it. If it's an arbitrary one, change the number. In all cases, you can use the above code and then access the `$sources` array as needed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: when I returned `$images->item(0);` and echoed it, gives error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in`

Comment: That's because it's a DOMElement. That's like trying to do `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0])` in JavaScript.